# Issues with Pyramid and traversal

Tags: python, pyramid, traversal

When I tried to point my url to `http://localhost:6543/admin/product/50b0d01ce815af3c4167040e/edit`, somehow it shows a 404 error. I believe somewhere, my views is wrong, but I can't seem to find out what went wrong after numerous tries.

Contents of `resources.py`:

```
    from pyramid.security import Authenticated
    from pyramid.security import Allow
    from pyramid.response import Response


    class Root(object):
        __name__ = ''
        __parent__ = None

        def __init__(self, request):
            pass

        def __getitem__(self, key):

            if key == 'admin_login':
               return Admin()

            elif key == 'admin':
               return Admin()

            raise KeyError


    class Admin(object):

        __name__ = ''
        __parent__ = Root
        __acl__ = [
          (Allow, Authenticated, 'admin')
        ]

        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def __getitem__(self, key):

            if key == 'product':
               print ('admin: ' , key)
               return Product()

            if key == 'category':
               print ('admin: ' + key)
               return Category()

            raise KeyError


    class Product(object):

        __name__ = ''
        __parent__ = Admin
        __acl__ = [
          (Allow, Authenticated, 'admin')
        ]

        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def __getitem__(self, key):
            if key :
               return ProductName(key)

            print ('Approaching KeyError: ', key)
            raise KeyError


    class ProductName(object):

        __parent__ = Product
        __acl__ = [
            (Allow, Authenticated, 'admin')
        ]

        def __init__(self, _str):
            self.__name__ = _str;
            self.__parent__ = Settings;

            print ('ProductName: ' + _str)
            pass
```

Contents of `views/admin.py`:

```
    @view_config(context='mycart:resources.Product', renderer='post.jinja2')
    @view_config(context='mycart:resources.ProductName', name='edit', renderer='admin/settings/commissions.jinja2', permission = 'admin')
        print (' in product edit? ')
        return {'msg': 'yay editing!'}
```

---

I've made some changes to the source code. `http://localhost:6543/admin/product` is definitely working. However, seems like now `http://localhost:6543/admin/product/add` isn't showing the layout nor is `http://localhost:6543/admin/product/YYYY/edit` showing the layout.

Contents of `views/admin.py`:

```
    @view_config(context='mycart:resources.ProductName', name='edit',    renderer='admin/product/test.jinja2', permission = 'admin')
    def product_edit(context, request):
        print 'edit here?'
        return { 'msg': '<div class="alert alert-success">Product Edit!</div>'}

    @view_config(context='mycart:resources.ProductName', name='add', renderer='admin/product/test.jinja2', permission = 'admin')
    def product_add(context, request):
        print 'add in here?'
        return { 'msg': '<div class="alert alert-success">Product Add</div>'}

    @view_config(context='mycart:resources.ProductName',  name="add" , request_method="POST", renderer='admin/product/add.jinja2', permission = 'admin')
    def product_add_post(context, request):
    return { 'msg': '<div class="alert alert-success">Product Added Successfully!</div>'}

    @view_config(context='mycart:resources.Product', name='', renderer='admin/product/list.jinja2', permission = 'admin')
    def product_list(context, request):

        return { 'msg': '<div class="alert alert-success">Listing of products</div>'}
```

Contents of `resources.py`:

```
    from pyramid.security import Authenticated
    from pyramid.security import Allow
    from pyramid.response import Response

    class Root(object):
        __name__ = __parent__ = None

        def __init__(self, request):
            pass

        def __getitem__(self, key):

            if key == 'admin_login':
                return Admin()

            elif key == 'admin':
                return Admin()

           raise KeyError


    class Admin(object):

        __name__ = ''
        __parent__ = Root
        __acl__ = [
            (Allow, Authenticated, 'admin')
        ]

        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def __getitem__(self, key):

            if key == 'product':
               return Product()

           #if key == 'category':
          #    return Category()

            raise KeyError

    class Product(object):
        __name__ = ''
        __parent__ = Admin
        __acl__ = [
            (Allow, Authenticated, 'admin')
        ]

        def __init__(self):
            print ('Product() self _name: ' , self.__name__, ' parent: ', self.__parent__)
            pass

        def __getitem__(self, key):
            print ('product: ' , key)

            if key:
                print ('key is true: ' , key)
                return ProductName(key)

            raise KeyError

     class ProductName(object):
        __name__ = ''
        __acl__ = [
           ( Allow, Authenticated, 'admin')
        ]

        def __init__(self, _key):
            p = Product()
            p.__name__ = _key
            p.__parent__ = self

            print ( 'ProductName() init: ', _key)
            print ( p.__parent__)
            print ( p.__name__)

            print ('\n\n')
            pass


        def __getitem__(self, _key):
            print ( 'ProductName() __get__item key: ', _key)

            if _key == 'edit':
                p = Product()
                p.__name__ = _key
                p.__parent__ = self
                print ('ProductName()->edit  parent: ')
                print ( p.__parent__)
                print ( p.__name__)
                print ('\n\n')
                return p

            raise KeyError
```

In my console, when I point my url to `http://localhost:6543/admin/product/add`, the output is:

```
    < mycart.resources.ProductName object at 0x10abb7990 >
    add
```

However, it is showing a 404 error, so I'm guessing my `views/admin.py` is wrong somewhere? I've tried switching the order of the view_config around, but to no avail:

```
    @view_config(context='mycart:resources.ProductName', name='add',  ... )
    ....

    @view_config(context='mycart:resources.ProductName', name='edit',  ... )
```

As for when editing using the following url: `http://localhost:6543/admin/vendor/50b0d01ce815af3c4167040e/edit`, the console output is:

```
    < mycart.resources.ProductName object at 0x10abb4bd0 >
    edit
```

So I know that in my context, I should use context='mycart:resources.ProductName', and the name set it edit. However, it isn't showing the edit message in the console that I have set in the `views/admin.py`.

Where could I have gone wrong?

Comment: Your view references `ProductName` but your `Product` resource i loading `SettingsName`. Is this a copy/paste issue, or your real problem?

Comment: On a side note, the `__parent__` attribute should be an actual instance, not a class. Thus you should be doing something like `p = Product(); p.__parent__ = self; return p`. If you don't fix that you will be posting another question later about an obscure error.

Comment: Oh, that should be a ProductName instead of SettingsName, I noticed that error after posting it in here and forgot to edit the post. Thanks, I'm gonna give it a try again.

Comment: Would there happen to be a step by step guide for dummy regarding traversal + mongodb that teaches something like localhost:6543/admin/product/{arbitrary_url} ,localhost:6543/admin/settings/{arbitrary_url} ,etc for people who have no background on python / pyramid? I've tried looking around but most of them assumed that folks have minimal knowledge of pylon.

Comment: so for the __parent__, if it should be an actual instance, if the url is localhost:6543/admin/product, in the product class ( resources.py ), should the __parent__ = Admin(); , and the productname __parent__ = Product()?

Comment: @MichaelMerickel I've edited my original post to reflect the changes I've made and the output in the console, would you be so kind to advise me further? cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

If you do `if key == 'somefing'` in `__getitem__` it is sign that you don't need pure traversal.
Use URLdispatch or Hybrid aproach.

ADDED:`localhost:6543/admin/product/add` shows not found, becoze you register 'add' view for ProductName, but from this path you get Product object, that have not view 'add' registred for it, thats why 404 not found

Comment: but does that explain why the views isn't working? this is purely an exercise for me to learn how traversal works, even though the terminal is showing the relevant messages

Comment: hm... in the terminal console, I'm getting  <mycart.resources.ProductName object at 0x10909bd50>
add , so I believe that the context is ProductName instead of Product.  Nonetheless, I've changed the Context to Product, and the name to add, but nope, it's still showing 404

Comment: what about the 2nd question posed, regarding the < mycart.resources.ProductName object at 0x10abb4bd0 >
    edit ... Been trying different ways, but somehow it isn't rendering the edit view

Comment: HA, I got it, just need to remove the __getitem__ in ProductName, leave __init__ as it is and remove the pass, thanks for the help nonetheless =D